# Is there a way to configure nginx to get more score on Google PageSpeed Insight?

Tags: wordpress, performance, nginx, server, pagespeed

I'm optimizing my WordPress website Mobile score to be more than 50 on Google PageSpeed Insight I've optimized the site some of the things i've done are minified, defer, leverage caching, expiry headers, images optimization, lazy loading, caching etc My website is on nginx is there any settings or configuration for nginx that could help improve the score on Google Insights or improve performance anything will do thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a list of audits you failed in google page speed

Comment: Defer unused CSS
Eliminate render-blocking resources
Properly size images
Defer unused CSS
Serve images in next-gen formats (which I've done already but still shows) .        Our website link is http://ts-treppenlifte.de/muenchen